# Repository pattern - Can repositories contain logic other than core CRUD

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern

So I understand that the repository pattern is used for multiple reasons, one of them being to abstract the interaction with a data source.

My question is how simple or complex repository methods should be. Is a repository purely to abstract the CORE methods e.g. get, set, update, delete of the data source or is okay to add very niche methods like `getCountOfUsersThatAreDisabled` to repositories. By okay I mean is that where methods like this fit into the picture, or should I place them outside the repository class.

```
// Laravel Example    

protected $user; //

public function __construct(User $user){
     $this->user = $user;
}

public function getCountOfUsersThatAreDisabled(){
     $this->user->where('disabled', 1);
}

public function find($user_id){ 
     return $this->user->find($user_id);
}
```

Comment: `...or is okay to add very niche methods like getCountOfUsersThatAreDisabled to repositories` It is okay, and common practice. This is where those types of things should go.

Comment: okay cool. I'm new to the whole repository concept and was just making sure that I am doing it right and not overcomplicating my repository classes.

Comment: can repository methods contain both sql and procedural code that ultimately together are used to return a result.

Comment: Yes, the whole point of a Repository is to provide a standard interface for your application to retrieve data. Your methods can be based on ORM models, query builders or raw SQL queries so long as the same data is returned

Answer (score 0):

Your way is fine, and putting your interaction-with-model code in repositories is perfectly OK, in fact, that's definitely the way it should be.

But as of your method :

```
public function getCountOfUsersThatAreDisabled(){
     $this->user->where('disabled', 1);
}
```

I'd prefer shortening the method name, and add the where-method arguments as the main methods arguments.

```
public function getCountOfUsers(array $where=["disabled", 1]){
     call_user_func_array([$this->user, "where"] , $where);
}
```

This way your methods is more readable and more generic, you can use it for different WHERE values too, even when you want to pass more that 2 arguments to the where method (Ex: $where= ["id", ">", 100]).

Hope this helps.